# bashscript remove strings in file

Tags: linux, string, bash

I want to remove from an input file every word ".xx" that appears on every line.  how can this be done?
input

```
hello.xx
my.xx
```

output

```
hello
my
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sed`:

```
sed -i.old 's/\.xx$//' infile
```

Answer (score 2):

As title, for a shell script to accomplish it, it is doable:

test.sh

```
#/bin/sh
while read line; do
    echo ${line%.xx}
done < input.txt
```

input file

```
$ cat input.txt
hello.xx
my.xx
```

testdriving

```
$ ./test.sh
hello
my
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following pattern:

If remove .xx from everywhere

```
s/\.xx//g
```

If remove .xx only at the end

```
s/\.xx$//g
```